# Comparing DLL sets from the same app on two different machines

Tags: configuration-management, dll

Is there a good way to compare the DLLs loaded between two machines running the same app. (And to replicate the process between N other machines, two at a time?)

Background: I am trying to track down a configuration/setup issue. It's the age-old, DLL-hell-type problem where an app will run on one machine but not on another.

I have eliminated our installer as an issue; it's stable but there are differences between the target systems. Different Windows flavors, MDAC versions etc.

I have tried: exporting EXE snapshots with Proc Explorer to a delimited file and using Excel to do the comparison. But this is very time-consuming and error prone. (I'm not ruling out Excel as a possibility, i just don't know enough tricks to use it to my ends.)

(I initially posted this question on StackOverflow but it resulted in a tumbleweed. Hoping for better luck here. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to write a whole script for you, but you could call h`andle.exe -p process_name.exe`, grep for the DLL(s) that you care about (maybe all of them), and then run `sigcheck` against each of them. Sigcheck has different options, including filehashing if you can't depend on the reported version information.

handle and sigcheck are also from SysInternals.

Comment: What will handle.exe give me that process explorer doesn't?

Comment: handle.exe is a CLI tool, thus scriptable. Same with sigcheck. I described the flow in my answer. Your tool for pattern matching will depend on the scripting language you choose - you could definitely do this with Perl or PS, probably without even needing intermediate files. I wouldn't try this in BAT, but VBS would probably do well too.

Comment: i get it. Thanks for the explanation. i will try that approach.